# Why is there so little support for the Minority SafePack in Western European countries, despite them supposedly being pro-multiculturalism?

Tags: european-union, minorities

In many countries in Western Europe, there is often a rhetoric about how much multiculturalism and diversity is valued, and in the meantime countries in Eastern Europe are often labeled as being too nationalistic and are often accused of oppressing the rights of minorities.

What is then the explanation, that the [Minority SafePack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority_SafePack) achieved so little support in the western part of the EU, especially in the most liberal and allegedly pro-multiculturalism countries, while several countries in the eastern part of the EU gave orders of magnitude more supporters?

Countries like Germany, the UK, Sweden, the Netherlands, provided extremely few supporters, despite being well-known for claiming to value diversity and multiculturalism.

Comment: There are so many things going on, about which I have never heard. Some are worthwhile, most are not.

Comment: Perhaps the name has something to do with it?  At least in (American) English, labelling something a "Pack" implies that it's a physical object holding a thing or number of things.  So calling something a "Minority SafePack" implies (or at least that's what I thought until I followed the link) that it's something like the emergency kit you might keep in your house or car.

Answer (score 10):

Speaking as a reasonably politically engaged Brit, I can safely say that the main reason that there isn't much interest from the UK is that most people wouldn't have heard of this initiative.

I would conjecture this is for two reasons.

Firstly, and I appreciate it's important to you but, the UK's engagement is somewhat dominated by Brexit currently, so fairly peripheral initiatives, or even Bills, are not going to get much attention.

Secondly, the proposal is pretty lame. It's basically suggesting that the EU says some nice things about minorities and throws a bit of money in their direction. In the UK, politically engaged linguistic and national minorities have, by and large, a lot more autonomy/power than that. I'm thinking the Scots, Welsh and Irish here. There are some exceptions but they're either not numerically large e.g. the Cornish or their languages/cultures aren't particularly threatened e.g. Hindi speakers. Where we do have significant issues, this proposal isn't going to get close to addressing them. I'm thinking about the prevalent attitude to Islam here.

As a consequence of these, the politicians and journalists who would normally bring these things to the public's attention are unlikely to feel it's worth the effort. Essentially, there are bigger fish to fry as it's unlikely to have any material effect on our cultural or linguistic diversity. Or address any of our actual issues.

Now, I appreciate that you may argue that, even if it's not that important to the UK, we have a lot of people who could help bring it to fruition for others for whom it is important. And I have much sympathy with that position. But the timing sucks unfortunately.

Comment: I think the same. Most Western either do not have linguistic minorities (e.g. Portugal) or those who have already have protections in place (the big exception would be France). So even people supporting the manifest will not be very pressed to promote it, as it would not affect them directly.

Answer (score 6):

On first glance, this package (never heard of it before) seems to support European minorities only. For instance, they gave the example of Bretons. In my opinion, the diversity and multiculturalism publicly professed by Western European countries mainly extend to non-European minorities. As a German, for me the word "multiculturalism" evokes non-Europeanness.

> As historian Rita Chin observes in her book The Crisis of Multiculturalism in Europe, multiculturalism has largely been opposed by Europe's minorities because of its "surprisingly undemocratic effects" [source](https://www.theglobeandmail.com/opinion/europes-multicultural-fears-hide-an-integration-success-story/article37738042/)

So this Minority SafePack might be seen as antagonistic to the Western European idea of multiculturalism.

Answer (score 1):

I am German and despite having an interest in politics I had no idea about the "Minority Safepack".

It was completely buried by Trump's sacking, Merkel's new government, Skripal affair, the verdict of the murderer of a female Freibung student, the imprisonment of a gang of Hartz IV abusers and 1000 other more important things. Bad timing for the initiative.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have been advertised much in Germany, if at all.

Comment: @vsz It isn't even a topic which is particularly relevant in Germany, because treatment of "endemic" ethnic minorities in post-nazi Germany was never a topic many people complained about. The rights already granted to these minorities usually go beyond what this initiative is demanding.

Comment: What does Trump's sacking mean?

Comment: @K Dog Trump fired Rex Tillerson und McMaster at that time which were important enough to be mentioned in Germany.